# Can anyone explain the output of this code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#define sqr(i) i*i

int main()
{ 
        printf("%d %d", sqr(3), sqr(3+1));  //output 9,7
        return 0;`
}
```

why the out put is 9,7?
  can anybody explain with steps how that 7 is getting evaluated

Comment: Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: If you get that comma separated output, then it is indeed a mystery.

Comment: @RadLexus The OP probably doesn't know that the difference is important.

Comment: I would like to vote to reopen your question, because it is not a duplicate on my opinion. My problem is that you didn't even try to follow the [lowest spelling English standards](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) and thus it would poll the site. So I need to vote for leave it closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the macro you define but the definition is a pitfall itself:

```
#define sqr(i) i*i
```

when you do this
sqr(3) then this will be replaced and executed as **3*3** resulting **9**

**BUT HERE IS THE PROBLEM**

sqr(3+1)  will be replaced and executed as **3+1*3+1** resulting **3+3+1 =7**

because the parameter will not be resolved before is passed to the macro...

instead it will just make a dumb-replace, changing every coincidence of *i* for the parameter **3+1**

## Ergo:

your macro behaves

```
input    output 

3          9 
3+1        7 
4          16
```

Answer (score 2):

The macro `sqr(i) i*i` for `sqr(3+1)` will be evaluated to `3+1*3+1` which is ... `7`. Put the arguments of the macro in parentheses:

```
#define sqr(i) (i) * (i)
```

if you really want to use a macro for this.